# What does the path C/ci/spyderXXXXX/_h_env/pthonw.exe is?

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables, spyder

I am trying to make an anaconda installation works: my problem is that the spyder3.exe in C/User/Anaconda/Script gave me an error and Spyder freezes on the launcher picture:

```
Unable to create process using "C:\ci\spyder_156545666\_h_env\pythonw.exe"
```

I am not sure of what it means: is it the path of python that is not found? Is it a specific program?

I am:

- On Windows 8
- Installed Python 3.8
- Have pip but install and then uninstall spyder with pip
- Installed Anaconda with the .exe downloaded from their webpage

If I understand the problem, I think I could fix it, but I am also interested in a direct answer.

I found a [webpage](https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/410) with a similar problem but I don't really understand the given solution (which seems to be on Linux and using a "winpython").

Comment: You're missing the `:` between `C` and `User`. It should be `C:/User/...`

Comment: Yes. But I am not sure that C:/ci is C:/User, since my user name is not "ci"